# Access VBA Run-time error '3021' No current record - Concatenating multiple rows into one row

Tags: ms-access, vba, concatenation

For each "ConcatID", I want to concatenate "Major" into one row separated by a ";"

```
Source table:
ConcatID    Major
A           Math
A           English
A           Theatre
B           Math
C           Biology

Target table:
A           Math; English; Theatre
B           Math
C           Biology
```

The code runs and performs what I need it to do, but I get this error "Run-time error '3021' No current record" on this line of code

```
Do While (ID_prev = rs_source![ConcatID].Value And Not (rs_source.EOF))
```

.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Concat()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database

    Dim rs_source As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs_target As DAO.Recordset

    Dim MajorList As String 'Placeholder for concatenating list of college majors
    Dim ID_prev As String 'Retains ID from previous record

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rs_source = dbs.OpenRecordset("tbl_ConcatMajorsSource") 'many records per student/college
    Set rs_target = dbs.OpenRecordset("tbl_ConcatMajorsTarget") 'one record per student/college
    dbs.Execute ("DELETE * FROM tbl_ConcatMajorsTarget") 'clear out table

    ID_prev = rs_source![ConcatID].Value ' set equal to first ID
    MajorList = rs_source![Major].Value ' set equal to first major
    rs_source.MoveNext ' move to the second record

    Do While Not (rs_source.EOF)
        Do While (ID_prev = rs_source![ConcatID].Value And Not (rs_source.EOF))
            MajorList = rs_source![Major].Value & "; " & MajorList 'concatenate majors
            rs_source.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs_target.AddNew ' add new record in target table
        rs_target![ConcatID].Value = ID_prev ' populate ID
        rs_target![Major].Value = MajorList ' populate MajorList
        rs_target.Update
        ID_prev = rs_source![ConcatID].Value ' set ID_prev to the new ID
        MajorList = "" 'blank out MajorList
    Loop

    rs_source.Close
    rs_target.Close
    Set rs_source = Nothing
    Set rs_target = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's because a record can't be read when the recordset reaches EOF. Thus:

```
    Do While Not rs_source.EOF
        If ID_prev = rs_source![ConcatID].Value Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            MajorList = rs_source![Major].Value & "; " & MajorList 'concatenate majors
            rs_source.MoveNext
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Thank you - This got rid of the error, but then I got the same error in the outer loop on the  ~ID_prev = rs_source![ConcatID].Value~ line.  I added an ~If rs_source.EOF~ to that and that seems to have solved it.  It seems like it is ignoring the EOF conditionals.  Any idea why?  Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, great. No, it is not ignoring it, but both conditions are validated. Thus, if any fails, so will the complete expression.